# push the object to array, according to order number in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below array i have 5 objects, with random order value, need to arrange the array as per the order key in object

i want push each object another array as per order.

```
  var array =  [
    {

        "name": {
            "text": "javascript"
        },
        "order": {
            "text": "4"
        }

    },
    {

        "name": {
            "text": "angualr js"
        },
        "order": {
            "text": "2"
        }
    },
 {

        "name": {
            "text": "Ios"
        },
        "order": {
            "text": "3"
        }
    },
 {

        "name": {
            "text": "PHP"
        },
        "order": {
            "text": "5"
        }
    }, {

        "name": {
            "text": "C"
        },
        "order": {
            "text": "5"
        }
    }
]
```

can any explain how to follow the logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just sort the array with [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), it accepts a function as parameter to compare two items.

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseInt(a.order.text, 10) - parseInt(b.order.text, 10);
});
```

Comment: Could you at least give some explanation about your code?

Comment: I think `return (+a.order.text) - (+b.order.text)` might be good as well.

Comment: @JinyoungKim which works, but not a "natural" way. People expect parseInt return an integer, but won't expect +"string" return integer.

Comment: I'd note that this solution will change the order of items in ```array```. So, if @Galaba really wants to have another array sorted, that's what is needed:
```var sortedArray = array.slice();

sortedArray.sort(function(a, b) {

  return parseInt(a.order.text, 10) - parseInt(b.order.text, 10);

});```